# Integrate play framework with maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

I trying to integrate play framework (java version) with maven and intellij idea.
For that i use play2-maven-plugin (https://code.google.com/p/play2-maven-plugin/);

I create pom file, as it described in the manual.
Now pom file looks like that:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>org.sigmaps</groupId>
   <artifactId>afrodita</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>play2</packaging>

   <name>Afrodita</name>

   <repositories>
       <repository>
           <id>typesafe</id>
           <name>Typesafe - releases</name>
           <url>http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/</url>
           <snapshots>
               <enabled>false</enabled>
           </snapshots>
       </repository>
   </repositories>

   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

       <play2.version>2.3.3</play2.version>
       <scala.version>2.10.4</scala.version>

       <play2.plugin.version>1.0.0-alpha8</play2.plugin.version>
       <sbt-compiler.plugin.version>1.0.0-beta4</sbt-compiler.plugin.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
           <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
           <version>${scala.version}</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
           <artifactId>play_2.10</artifactId>
           <version>${play2.version}</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
           <artifactId>play-java_2.10</artifactId>
           <version>${play2.version}</version>
       </dependency>


   </dependencies>

   <build>
       <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/app</sourceDirectory>
       <resources>
           <resource>
               <directory>${basedir}/conf</directory>
           </resource>
           <resource>
               <directory>${basedir}</directory>
               <includes>
                   <include>public/**</include>
               </includes>
           </resource>
       </resources>

       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>com.google.code.play2-maven-plugin</groupId>
               <artifactId>play2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${play2.plugin.version}</version>
               <extensions>true</extensions>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
```

In intellij Idea, on Maven projects tab I click plugins => play2 => paly2:run

And then give an error:

```
[INFO] [play2:run {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] null
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.code.play2.plugin.AbstractPlay2ServerMojo.getProjectClassPath(AbstractPlay2ServerMojo.java:151)    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Afrodita
[INFO]    task-segment: [com.google.code.play2-maven-plugin:play2-maven-plugin:1.0.0-alpha8:run]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [play2:run {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] null
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.code.play2.plugin.AbstractPlay2ServerMojo.getProjectClassPath(AbstractPlay2ServerMojo.java:151)
    at com.google.code.play2.plugin.AbstractPlay2ServerMojo.prepareAntJavaTask(AbstractPlay2ServerMojo.java:70)
    at com.google.code.play2.plugin.AbstractPlay2RunMojo.internalExecute(AbstractPlay2RunMojo.java:91)
    at com.google.code.play2.plugin.AbstractPlay2Mojo.execute(AbstractPlay2Mojo.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 24 12:41:25 MSK 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/299M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 1
    at com.google.code.play2.plugin.AbstractPlay2ServerMojo.prepareAntJavaTask(AbstractPlay2ServerMojo.java:70)
    at com.google.code.play2.plugin.AbstractPlay2RunMojo.internalExecute(AbstractPlay2RunMojo.java:91)
    at com.google.code.play2.plugin.AbstractPlay2Mojo.execute(AbstractPlay2Mojo.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Then I try sbt-compiler => sbt-compiler:compile and that gives me another error:

```
[INFO] Building Afrodita
[INFO]    task-segment: [com.google.code.sbt-compiler-maven-plugin:sbt-compiler-maven-plugin:1.0.0-beta4:compile]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [sbt-compiler:compile {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] An invalid artifact was detected.

This artifact might be in your project's POM, or it might have been included transitively during the resolution process. Here is the information we do have for this artifact:

    o GroupID:     <<< MISSING >>>
    o ArtifactID:  sbt-compiler-sbt0135
    o Version:     <<< MISSING >>>
    o Type:        jar

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.artifact.InvalidArtifactRTException: For artifact {null:sbt-compiler-sbt0135:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty.
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.validateIdentity(DefaultArtifact.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.<init>(DefaultArtifact.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:40)
    at com.google.code.sbt.compiler.plugin.AbstractSBTCompileMojo.getResolvedArtifact(AbstractSBTCompileMojo.java:547)
    at com.google.code.sbt.compiler.plugin.AbstractSBTCompileMojo.getWellKnownSbtCompiler(AbstractSBTCompileMojo.java:685)
    at com.google.code.sbt.compiler.plugin.AbstractSBTCompileMojo.getSbtCompiler(AbstractSBTCompileMojo.java:635)
    at com.google.code.sbt.compiler.plugin.AbstractSBTCompileMojo.internalExecute(AbstractSBTCompileMojo.java:287)
    at com.google.code.sbt.compiler.plugin.SBTCompileMojo.internalExecute(SBTCompileMojo.java:102)
    at com.google.code.sbt.compiler.plugin.AbstractSBTCompileMojo.execute(AbstractSBTCompileMojo.java:247)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

If I try to run project with activator, thats runs ok.
What I shood do to solve that problem and run project with maven, and without SBT?

Answer (score 0):

The [play2:run](https://play2-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavensite/1.0.0-alpha8/play2-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) goal has an `executedProject` parameter which is optional. Without having ever used play2 my first guess is that it is not where the goal assumes it to be. Do you see to which value it is  actually set if you run `mvn ... -e -X` (to print errors and debugging info)?

Answer (score 0):

The first problem (with play2) - in 1.0.0-alpha9 the error message was improved, now it tells what to do in this case. It's part of issue https://code.google.com/p/play2-maven-plugin/issues/detail?id=29, see last comment.

The second problem (with sbt-compiler) was fixed in 1.0.0-beta5 - see issue https://code.google.com/p/sbt-compiler-maven-plugin/issues/detail?id=14.